# Working with modules on the local dev server for Java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developing a Google Appengine Java application and I am facing a major challenge testing with the local dev server. I dumped the Eclipse tools cause I'm more flexible with Netbeans and 
I am using Appengine Maven plugin for my development.

This is my sample project structure :

**myapp**
    module-endpoints
    module-web
    module-ear
     **pom.xml**

The application works when I build with `mvn clean install` on the root folder(myapp) and also when I use the `mvn appengine:devserver` command to run the module-ear application, however I can't seem to access the cloud endpoints via `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api`. I can only access the endpoint's API via the dynamically issued port when I access it via the admin console `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`.

The issue with this is that when testing cloud-endpoint Javascript client on the module-web project according to tutorials I am supposed to use `localhost:8080/_ah/api` as my url to test. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct URL for the local API explorer?  It should be `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` (but actually it's a redirect).  Did you know you can specify a `<port></port>` in the `<plugin><configuration>` of your application's `pom.xml`?

Comment: U know when you run an ear application on the dev server it generates a random port for the cloud-endpoints application , if you check your console you will find the two applications listed , the war application will run on 8080 while the cloud-endpoints application runs on a different port (mostly random for each run) .If i access the endpoints module e.g http://localhost:6789/_ah/api/explorer it works but when i try accessing it like this http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer it doesn't .Thanks.

Comment: Right, the application I was looking at had endpoints in the same module. Maybe I'll try splitting the endpoints or into a new module and see if I can reproduce the problem. Is your endpoints module the default module?

Comment: @tx802 no my endpoints module ain't the default module.

Comment: @tx802 All the tutorials say use this url http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/ , the explorer url  seems to me like the url for testing the endpoints service methods , while the _ah/api applies to client side access to the endpoint service methods.

Comment: @tx802 it worked when I made endpoint module the default module.Is it proper to publish the ear application this way to GAE?.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is still actual you could always update your pom.xml with flags so that the ports of all your modules are defined:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <port>8080</port>
      <jvmFlags>
        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
        <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
        <jvmFlag>-Dcom.google.appengine.devappserver_module.mymodule2.port=9090</jvmFlag>
      </jvmFlags>
      <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then you could use localhost:9090/_ah/api/explorer to test your APIs

Comment: Seriously @Herring, how did you know about `devappserver_module.mymodule2.port`? Do you have any other golden pieces of knowledge?? Have you run a ear setup in Intellij and see the "your working directory `ear-xxx` doesn't match `ear-xxx/module-xxx` so no `new File("WEB-INF")`'s work anymore?

Answer (score 2):

If you have several modules deployed, you need to update your maven app engine launcher setup to recognize the different modules.  See the modules sample Java app at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java.

If you've already done that, then a dispatch.xml file will tell app engine how to route requests:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I made the endpoints project the default module.

Answer (score 0):

**dispatch.xml** is ignored on devserver, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing#dispatch_files) states the following.

> **Dispatch files**
>
> All dispatch files are ignored when running the development server.
>   The only way to target instances is through their ports.

This means that only the *default module* will be reachable at the configured port (typically 8888 or 8080). I have just tested it with app engine 1.9.25 and it does not work, so no improvement has been made.

On the other hand you can always refer to the module by its port. The module's location is logged in the console when the application starts, you will see something like:

> INFO: Module instance module2-auto is running at `http://localhost:37251/`

In my case this was useless since I was expecting to make AJAX requests to different modules by using the same host (but different urls). For instance:

Comment: Here's how I solved the problem you mentioned ("I was expecting to make AJAX requests to different modules by using the same host (but different urls)"): http://blog.tomtasche.at/2015/12/multi-module-dispatcher-for-appengine.html